# How many zero divisors at $\mathbb{Z}_{80}\times\mathbb{Z}_{100}$?

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

How many zero divisors at $\mathbb{Z}_{80}\times\mathbb{Z}_{100}$?
I assume it: $(80-\varphi(80))\cdot(100-\varphi(100))$,
I'm right or I miss somthing??

Thank you!

Comment: It's almost never good to assume some random quantity is a solution. When you give such information in the future, please include how you arrived at that, and don't say you *assumed* it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a,b)\in A\times B$ is a zero divisor iff $a$ is a zero divisor in $A$ or $b$ is a zero divisor in $B$. Note that e.g. $(1,0)$ is a zero divisor because $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)$.

So you should have $80\cdot 100-\phi(80)\cdot \phi(100)$ instead.

Comment: Can you can give me example please? for $(a,b)$ that $a$ is a zero divisor of $\mathbb{Z}_{80}$ and $b$ is **not** a zero divisor of  $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ and explain my why this is true? e.g. $(16,11)$ Thank you!

Comment: And why $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)$? Isn't should be $(1,1)$?